# SQL Query: Without using Subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

how can i get all the records from 1st table not present in the 2nd table without using subquery?
i would like to use Join...

Comment: Be aware that `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` does not perform as well as `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.someColumn
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. I just forget the few concept of joins. thanks for reminding...

Answer (score 2):

You can even use

a) `EXCEPT`

b) `Where Not in`

e.g.
  **Sample Data**

```
declare @t1 table(id1 int, recordsA varchar(20))
insert into @t1 
select 1,'record1' union all 
select 2,'record2' union all
select 3,'record3' union all
select 4,'record4' union all
select 5,'record5'

declare @t2 table(id2 int, recordsB varchar(20))
insert into @t2 
select 1,'record1' union all 
select 2,'record2' union all
select 3,'record3'
```

**Query:1**

```
select t1.id1,t1.recordsA from @t1  t1
except
select t2.id2,t2.recordsB from @t2 t2
```

**Query 2:**

```
select t1.id1,t1.recordsA from @t1  t1 
where  t1.recordsA not in(select t2.recordsB from @t2 t2)
```

**Output:**

```
id1 recordsA
4   record4
5   record5
```